# How to add and show data from a list of objects in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a ***Lexical Analyzer*** and I want to show all data on a table in MVC. But to simplify code I'll add an example to show what I want to achieve. I have a *logic.cs* class where the Lexical Analyzer will be receiving the string coming into, and I want to *Add* items to the List accordingly to the Lexical Analyzer method.

This is my code:

**Controller**

```
    Repository repo = new Repository();
    logic logica = new logic();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var getrepo = repo.GetData();
        return View(getrepo.ToList());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string str) {

        logica.Logic_t(str); //I send str parameter to the logic class
        var getrepo = repo.GetData();
        return View(getrepo.ToList());
```

**Model**

*Repository.cs*

```
 public class Repository
{
    public List<data_table> data = new List<data_table>() { };


    public List<data_table> GetData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

*data_table.cs*

```
  public int Line { get; set; }
  public string Token { get; set; }
```

*logic.cs*

```
 Repository repo = new Repository();

    public void Logic_t(string s)
    {
        int Line = 1;

        repo.data.Add(new data_table { Line =Line , Token = " NUMBER" });
    }
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<pruebaarray.Models.data_table>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <textarea rows="10" cols="50" class="textarea" name="str">

    </textarea>
    <input  type="submit" value="send-to-logic" class="btn btn-primary"/>
}

<table class="table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Line</th>
        <th>Token</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <th>@item.Line</th>
            <th>@item.Token</th>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

And this is my final view:

[image: my final view]

My code has **no** Errors, but when I click the *submit* button, **nothing** shows in the table. What am I missing? or what could be wrong?

PD: My Lexical Analyzer logic has recursive methods so It will be adding data constantly to the List.

**UPDATE**: I got this just by setting List to `static`

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your form does not know which controller or action to target.

`Html.BeginForm()` has several overloads.

**For example:**

```
BeginForm(HtmlHelper, String, String, Object, FormMethod, Object)
```

> Writes an opening  tag to the response and sets the action tag
>   to the specified controller, action, and route values. The form uses
>   the specified HTTP method and includes the HTML attributes.

Check the [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#overloads) here

Comment: I wrote `name="str"` in the textarea label, I think this should be enough?

Comment: No. Unless you use something like `string text=Request.Form["str"];` to get the content of the textarea.

Comment: Ok got you, I used `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))`. And I used the debbuger tool to see carefully what happends and everything is ok. In `repo.data.Add(new data_table { Line =Line , Token = " NUMBER" });` seems to add a List array into [0]. But when it returns to `var getrepo = repo.GetData();` , `var getrepo` is null or has no items. Looks like the lists cleans by itself. I don't know why.

Comment: I fixed this by just putting the List to `static`. If I found the solution by myself, should I delete this question?

Comment: You can do that.